# What is the use function in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm currently reading a c++ book and one of the function is

```
void fp(char v[]){
   for(char* p = v; *p!=0;p++) use(*p);
}
```

I wrote this into my editor and compiled it. I also included the headers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
```

But my terminal returns the following message:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'use'
```

I also google it and its nowhere to be found online, the function doesn't exist.

Comment: Apparently you missed something in your book where they wrote a function called `use`. It's not part of any standard library, so it's either something that was written by the book author or a typo. You should re-read that section of the book and its code to see if you can find the mistake.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup declared use() somewhere in the book. Its not a standard function in any C/C++ library.

Comment: You are simply iterating over the character string `v` using the pointer `p` until the *nul-termiating* character is encountered passing each character to the `use` function as you go. (which has no special meaning until your write a *type* `use (int c) { /* stuff */ }` function) For example `void use (int c) { printf ("%c has ASCII value %d\n", c, c); }`

Comment: Or for C++ use `std::cout << (char)c << " has ASCII value " << c << '\n';` instead of `printf`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Wrong sentence on EBCDIC platforms ;-)

Comment: Yep, that's an ASCII only job `:)`

Answer (score 6):

That's because there is no such standard library function.

The author is either using pseudo-code here, or has defined this function somewhere else in the book.